# JavaScript how to wait for click events to be processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor, combobox

I am writing a combobox that gets a list of movies from a database that contain the text that was typed into a input box. The comboxbox should be a drop down when the user select in the input box and hide when the input box goes out of focus. The problem is that when the user clicks on an item to select it, the input will get out of focus, the combobox hides and the click is lost. So I wanted to wait for all clicks to be processed before hiding the combobox. I have added a seTimeout do delay the hidding by 1s, but this is not very good because 1s is a bit long and lower values may make the combobox hide before the click. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function make_combobox() {
        $.get("/Clients/make_movies_table", { search_str: mov_text_sel.value }, function (data, status)
        {
            mov_sel.innerHTML=data;
        });
        $("#mov_sel").show();
    }

    function hide_combobox() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#mov_sel').hide();
        }, 1000);
        window.
    }


</script>

<input type="text" id="mov_text_sel" size="10" 
       onfocus="make_combobox()"
       oninput="make_combobox()"
       onblur="hide_combobox()"
/>
<div style="position:relative">
    <div id="mov_sel">
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code for a combobox row:

```
   <td class="combobox"
         onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = 'RoyalBlue'"
         onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'"
         onclick="mov_text_sel.value = '@rec.Title'">
         @rec.Title
   </td>
```

Comment: What do you mean the click is lost? It's hard to grasp what you want.

Comment: since the combobox is hidden, the click is not processed.